# vscode can not remotely debug php code under Homestead environment but I can debugged it one day ago

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

Yesterday I configured the relevant file to debug the Homestead-based laravel code，it can debug normally at that time through jonagoldman's answer on this [site](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug/issues/220) .But since I installed xdebug under windows to use it to debug the local PHP script file, it cannot be debugged remotely now.

I don't know if it's because the Xdebug between the local and Xdebug in Homestead have been in conflict. I've found a lot of information for this, but none of them solved it. If anyone can help me solve this problem, I will be very grateful to him.

My os is windows 10,Laravel is 5.5, php is 7.1.

Here are some of my configuration files.

- vscode launch.json:

  ```
  {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Listen for XDebug",
           "type": "PHP",
           "request": "launch",
           "port": 9000
       },
       {
           "name": "Launch currently open script",
           "type": "PHP",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${file}",
           "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
           "port": 9000
       },
       {
           "name": "Listen for XDebug on Homestead",
           "type": "PHP",
           "request": "launch",
           "pathMappings": {
               "/home/vagrant/Code": "E:/Code"
           },
           "port": 9000
       }]
  }
  ```
- Homestead Xdebug.ini:

  zend_extension=xdebug.so

  xdebug.auto_trace=1

  xdebug.remote_enable=1

  xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2

  xdebug.remote_port=9000

  xdebug.remote_autostart=1
- phpinfo() Xdebug settings

> xdebug
> xdebug support    enabled
> Version   2.5.5
> IDE Key   vagrant
> Supported protocols   Revision
> DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol   $Revision: 1.145 $
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> xdebug.auto_trace On  On
> xdebug.cli_color  0   0
> xdebug.collect_assignments    Off Off
> xdebug.collect_includes   On  On
> xdebug.collect_params 0   0
> xdebug.collect_return Off Off
> xdebug.collect_vars   Off Off
> xdebug.coverage_enable    On  On
> xdebug.default_enable On  On
> xdebug.dump.COOKIE    no value    no value
> xdebug.dump.ENV   no value    no value
> xdebug.dump.FILES no value    no value
> xdebug.dump.GET   no value    no value
> xdebug.dump.POST  no value    no value
> xdebug.dump.REQUEST   no value    no value
> xdebug.dump.SERVER    no value    no value
> xdebug.dump.SESSION   no value    no value
> xdebug.dump_globals   On  On
> xdebug.dump_once  On  On
> xdebug.dump_undefined Off Off
> xdebug.extended_info  On  On
> xdebug.file_link_format   no value    no value
> xdebug.force_display_errors   Off Off
> xdebug.force_error_reporting  0   0
> xdebug.halt_level 0   0
> xdebug.idekey no value    no value
> xdebug.max_nesting_level  256 256
> xdebug.max_stack_frames   -1  -1
> xdebug.overload_var_dump  2   2
> xdebug.profiler_aggregate Off Off
> xdebug.profiler_append    Off Off
> xdebug.profiler_enable    Off Off
> xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger    Off Off
> xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value  no value    no value
> xdebug.profiler_output_dir    /tmp    /tmp
> xdebug.profiler_output_name   cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
> xdebug.remote_addr_header no value    no value
> xdebug.remote_autostart   On  On
> xdebug.remote_connect_back    Off Off
> xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time  3600    3600
> xdebug.remote_enable  On  On
> xdebug.remote_handler dbgp    dbgp
> xdebug.remote_host    10.0.2.2    10.0.2.2
> xdebug.remote_log no value    no value
> xdebug.remote_mode    req req
> xdebug.remote_port    9000    9000
> xdebug.scream Off Off
> xdebug.show_error_trace   Off Off
> xdebug.show_exception_trace   Off Off
> xdebug.show_local_vars    Off Off
> xdebug.show_mem_delta Off Off
> xdebug.trace_enable_trigger   Off Off
> xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value no value    no value
> xdebug.trace_format   0   0
> xdebug.trace_options  0   0
> xdebug.trace_output_dir   /tmp    /tmp
> xdebug.trace_output_name  trace.%c    trace.%c
> xdebug.var_display_max_children   128 128
> xdebug.var_display_max_data   512 512
> xdebug.var_display_max_depth  3   3

- Homestead.yaml

  ---

  ip: "192.168.10.10"
  memory: 2048
  cpus: 1
  provider: virtualbox

  authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

  keys:
  - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

  folders:
  - map: e:/Code
  to: /home/vagrant/Code

  sites:

  ```
   - map: sample.test
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/sample/public

   - map: Demo.test
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/demo/public
  ```

  databases:
  - demo
  - sample

  variables:
  - key: APP_ENV
  value: local

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. But, I can debugged fixing launch.json.

My launch.json setting is below.

```
   {
      "name": "Homestead",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "pathMappings": {
   //     "/home/vagrant/code": "D:/workspace/laravel_work"  // can't work
          "/home/vagrant/code": "${workspaceRoot}"           // work
   //     "/home/vagrant/code": "D:\\workspace\\laravel_work"// work 
      },
      "port": 9000
    }
```

You should fix launch.json

```
{
    "name": "Listen for XDebug on Homestead",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "pathMappings": {
        //"/home/vagrant/Code": "E:/Code"
          "/home/vagrant/Code": "E:\\Code"
    },
    "port": 9000
}
```